# Ethernet will not work on Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: networking, server, ethernet

I have a ASRock H570 Phantom Gaming 4 motherboard

I am unable to ping any other devices

- When I ping duckduckgo.com I get "Temporary failure in name resolution"
- When I ping 8.8.8.8 or another computer on the local network I get "Network is unreachable"
- I tried to install net-tools and apache2 but they both gave the error "Temporary failure in name resolution"

I just installed my OS a few hours ago, everything is default and I have tested my Ethernet cable on other devices

`ip a`

```
1: 10: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host 10
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
inet6:1/128 scope host
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`sudo lshw -c network`

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Ethernet controller 
    product: Ethernet Connection (14) I219-V
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 1f.6
    bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
    version: 11
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi cap_list
    configuration: latency=0 
    resources: memory:92100000-9211ffff
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the network device is recognized and active? What is the output of `ip a` and `sudo lshw -c network`?

Comment: It seems that I need drivers for my Ethernet. How do I install them without internet?

Comment: Terminal output: sudo lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net or sudo lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3  Specification: https://asrockrack.com/MB/AMD/X570%20Phantom%20Gaming%204/index.asp#Specification  https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software  Good instruction, but in German: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Howto/Realtek-r8125/

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe -v e1000e` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I am having the same problem did you get any answers?

Comment: I installed Ubuntu server 20.10, and my network worked.